# Angular2 Dynamically add styles to styleUrls array

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm writing an app in Agular2, and some of our components allow for a parent adding style classes. Something like this:
Child component.

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-label-value',
templateUrl: './label-value.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./label-value.component.css']
})
export class LabelValueComponent implements OnInit {

@Input() label: string;
@Input() value: string;
@Input() valueClass: string;
@Input() labelClass: string;
@Input() cssFile: string;

getLabelClasses(){
  let classList = 'label-value-label '
  if (this.labelClass){
    classList += this.labelClass;
  }
  return classList;
}
```

Child Template:

```
<div [ngClass]="getLabelClasses()">
  {{label}}
</div>
```

Inside parent template.

```
<app-label-value 
  [label]="'Just text'" 
  [value]="'some text'"
  [labelClass]="'label-color standard-text'"
  [cssFile]="'./app.component.css'">
</app-label-value>
```

This does not work. The div gets the `label-value-label label-color standard-text` classes, but they aren't loaded from the `./app.component.css` class file (and so not displayed).
The child component needs to somehow find and add the `./app.component.css` path to the `styleUrls` array. Or some other method of telling the component where to look for the class file. But I can't seem to figure out how to do it (or even if it's possible).

Comment: Maybe are the class not charged. Can you try with: >>> in front of your class in the css file?

Comment: If you put label-value-label label-color standard-tex in the styles.css file, is it working?

Comment: Putting label-value-label label-color standard-text in the ./label-value.component.css works, obviously. But I want to allow the parent to feed the child its own (or any other) css file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was `ViewEncapsulation`.
Once I set `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` on the parent component, then its CSS file was visible to all other components, including my child component. So I had no need to manually include the CSS file in my child component's `styleUrls` array, the browser found it amyway.
Of course, the best solution would be to put all "global" styles in the style.css file in the app root.

Answer (score 1):

Sharing Style Sheet from Parent to Child or Even Child to Parent is not yet feasible in Angular4
You will have access to the only styles you mention in the component's style sheet.

But you do have an option to include multiple style sheets for a component. Right there in the component, you can have a list of style sheets.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-component',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css', './someother.css', './another.css']
})
```

If you want to have a style available for the entire project you can write it in style.css which is compiled globally and not specific to a component.